# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.ImportConstants$ConstantsMap, when using OmniFaces o:importConstants

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

We use,

- JSF 2.1
- RichFaces 4
- OmniFaces 1.5.

We are getting the following exception:

```
 java.io.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.ImportConstants$ConstantsMap
```

This when using `<o:importConstants>` and `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` as client.

Has anyone seen this before? What would be the fix?

Thanks for any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? (and if server-provided, which server impl/version?). I'm unable to reproduce it with Mojarra 2.1.28 and MyFaces 2.1.15 on Tomcat 7.0.47 with the said state saving method. At least, the **smallest possible** XHTML file which still reproduces the problem by copy'n'paste'n'running it unmodified, would be very helpful as well. By the way, I know how the fix it, but I'd love to understand the cause first. As of now, I can't reproduce it and therefore I don't understand it :) There must be something weird going on with state saving (perhaps an outdated JSF impl version).

Comment: @balusc Bauke, we are using Mojarra 2.1 running on Websphere. If I comment out the state saving, it works fine. 

`<o:importConstants type="com...web.beans.Constants" />
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{handler.method(Constants.constant1, Constants.constant2)}" />` 

This is code similar to what we have. I will try to come up with some code that you can copy/paste and run.
I will also try to update to mojarra 2.1.28 and try it.

Comment: Which Mojarra 2.1 version?

Comment: @BalusC it is Mojarra 2.1.9.SNAPSHOT

Comment: Reproduced when I add the said `<f:event>` whereby such a constant is specified as method argument, also on 2.1.28. Interesting. Looking into it ...

Comment: @BalusC I tried with Mojarra 2.1.28 as well and get the same error :(. I also updated my omnifaces to 1.7 as well. Sorry, repllied before seeing your comment. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is simple, just let `org.omnifaces.util.MapWrapper` implement `Serializable` as well. I've [committed](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/2dfed7e2ce56996a0e13fe58ca69addd757c22d2) it and it's available in today's latest [1.8 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.8-SNAPSHOT/). However, the cause is just weird. I didn't expect it to be saved into JSF state as it's an EL expression. So I looked a bit further, just to learn.

For sake of completeness, here's the stacktrace I encountered with Mojarra 2.1.28 on Tomcat 7.0.47 with client side state saving and a `<f:event>` whereby a constant is being passed as method argument like so:

```
<o:importConstants type="com.example.Constants" />
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.method(Constants.SOME)}" />
```

The exception already occurs when just opening the page, no postback was necessary.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.ImportConstants$ConstantsMap
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1181)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionLiteral.writeExternal(ValueExpressionLiteral.java:109)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1456)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.el.lang.VariableMapperImpl.writeExternal(VariableMapperImpl.java:59)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1456)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.writeExternal(MethodExpressionImpl.java:308)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1456)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.writeExternal(TagMethodExpression.java:152)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1456)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1541)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1506)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1375)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1171)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:464)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And riiight .. The [`ValueExpressionLiteral`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el/7.0.47/org/apache/el/ValueExpressionLiteral.java#ValueExpressionLiteral) comes into the picture. Enum values are resolved as EL literals. The `ValueExpressionLiteral` will serialize the literal value (the evaluated value itself) for state saving instead of the concrete expression `#{Constants.SOME}`. This makes after all sense, enums are constants anyway.

Comment: Awesome! I pulled in the latest snapshot and that worked and your explanation makes sense. I was getting the same stack trace as well. As always you have quickly provided a solution :) and we really appreciate what you have done with omnifaces and how useful it has become.